# Laravel/React - "Call to a member function validated() on null" when creating a different FormRequest in Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I'm trying to validate two different types of data in a single axios call: Profile and ProfileSocial. The problem is, when I create a ProfileSocialRequest based on the second model and try to validate it, it returns `Call to a member function validated() on null`; if I return the data ***before*** attempting to validate it, it returns a valid object.

---

**ProfileSocial**

```php
class ProfileRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
       return [
            'name' => [
                'required',
                'string',
            ],
            ...
            'socials' => [
                'required',
                'array',
                'min:1',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

**ProfileSocialRequest**

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ProfileSocialRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'profile_id' => [
                'required',
                'integer',
            ],
            'social_type_id' => [
                'required',
                'integer',
            ],
            'handle' => [
                'required',
                'string',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

**ProfileController**

```php
public function store(ProfileRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->validated(); // this (ProfileRequest) works fine

    $sosicalReq = new ProfileSocialRequest($request['socials'][0]); // This returns a valid object: {"social_type_id":1,"handle":"mySocialNetworkHandle","profile_id":1000}
    $socialReqData = $sr->validated(); // ERROR: Call to a member function validated() on null
    ...
}
```

My question is, why is `$socialReq` being read as null when calling validated() if every step of the way it returns a complete object?

Comment: Should it not be `$sosicalReq->validated()`

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, to but to manually create validation class instead of

```
$sosicalReq = new ProfileSocialRequest($request['socials'][0]);
```

you should use:

```
$sosicalReq = app()->make(ProfileSocialRequest::class);
```

but it will validate the whole input not just `$request['socials'][0]`

Comment: Ok, so I'm trying to run each of my `social` objects through the validation set on my `ProfileSocialRequest`. My logic was: validate the `ProfileRequest`, then run a loop through the `socials` array and validate each as a `ProfileSocialRequest`. In the question, I only use the first object though. @marcin-nabiałek

Comment: @brunouno You should then use array validation instead https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#validating-arrays and to it in single request class